# How to change from Fahrenheit to Celsius in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013 the weather is shown, but by default it's in Fahrenheit. How do I change it to Celsius?

Comment: -1, This is a trivial question that can be solved simply by looking through the program's settings, as you show below.

Comment: Well, I didn't find it immediately, had to do a google search for it and turns out I wasn't alone in looking for this. But since there was no entry on Superuser I thought it would be useful to add it. Seeing the incredible negative feedback here I'm thinking that was a mistake... Sorry for trying to do some good.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via File - Options - Calendar - Weather.
[image: Need to scroll all the way down to weather.]

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to post this.  I had exactly this question - like you, didn't find anything quickly with a Google & turned to Stackexchange SuperUser.    Found your Q&A.  Problem for me = sorted.            Therefore +1 on both Q & A